# How do you transport/stash your m1 macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, user-experience

I just bought an m1 Macbook pro. I've used macs a bunch, have a mac mini, but i've never owned a macbook. I kind of like it... with caveat of some annoyances. The biggest one yet being it takes 2 to 3 times as long to turn on from a shutdown as my Zenbook does and and even longer to click on your profile and type in your password than Windows Hello.

So...Do yall always have it in sleep when not using it or lugging it around? I rarely just let my Zenbook sleep since it only takes like 2 seconds to shut down and 6 seconds to turn on and log in. I also never know if it's going to be in my backpack for 30 minutes or 3 days.

I know I'm griping literally about 8 or 10 seconds, but I'm getting more irritated each time. Have Apple people just hyped these things up so much that I imagined it should minimally compete with if not outright spank my $900 zenbook? Thankfully I got it 200 off normal, and i originally had planned to sell my zenbook, but even though i like it, im thinking of returning it bc of how irritated im getting and keeping my zenbook.

And then I think about how my zenbook has an additional usb A and HDMI, weighs less, has a 14 inch screen in about the same footprint bc of slimmer bezzels. im so conflicted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacBooks can sleep for days, and if they get low on power while sleeping, they auto-hibernate (dump RAM to storage and fully power down).

If it's been asleep for many days and finally run out of battery and hibernated, then when you give it power and turn it on, it resumes from hibernation (loads the RAM image from storage back into RAM and resumes executing where it left off) in seconds.

So yes, Mac users just shut the lid and go. I'm kinda surprised to hear that some Windows laptop users don't.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I'll try to make myself stop shutting down hahah. I stopped doing it bc this one starts almost as fast from boot. So no worry how long I don't use it. But I want almost instant on when I do